# Function keeps looping same two numbers

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, collatz

So i'm trying to follow along in the Automate The Boring Stuff with Python book. There's a question that asks me to make the collatz sequence. One function collatz() will be processing the actual math, while the second function get_collatz() will be the one taking user input and running it through the collatz function until the returned number == 1. I apologize if this is a simple mistake, I may have had a little to drink as well as being new to the site and fairly new to coding also. Would appreciate it if someone could help to point me in the right direction. I don't want a straight up answer because I want to learn myself, would just like an idea of what could be going wrong here. Here is my code.

```
def collatz(number):
if number % 2 == 0:
    number //= 2
    print(number)
    return number
else:
    number = 3 * number + 1
    print(number)
    return number

def get_collatz():
number = int(input('Put in a number please!: '))
while number != 1:
    print(number)
    collatz(number)


get_collatz()
```

Comment: `I may have had a little to drink` - lol

Comment: Make sure your indentation syntax is correct - e.g., you're missing tabs under your `def`s.

Comment: Looking at my code in the IDE and the indentation is correct I must have messed up the formatting when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Asking only for a hint is not really how stackoverflow questions are meant to be. But if a hint you want, a hint you get :)

```
def get_collatz():
    number = int(input('Put in a number please!: '))
    while number != 1:
        print(number)
        collatz(number)
```

Your variable, number, is a simple integer. It changes its value only when you use an operation like

```
number = <something>
number += 2
```

**Hint:** You don't seem to use any of these operation inside your implementation of get_collatz(). Not other than the initial input, at least :).

Comment: I fixed it. I added number = collatz(number) to actually set the new number. Appreciate the help!